# Configuration of asp.net core using settings

Tags: configuration, web-config, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm evaluating asp.net core and .net core and I'm not yet sure about some things. In the past it was possible to configure many components using the web.config out of the box.
To name some examples:

- There was the membership-provider and I could implement many providers but I was able ton configure later which provider should be used. This was dependend of the use-case. Now I should use asp.net identity - but I can only find configurations that are performed in sourcecode.
- Same for authentication. I can define "CookieAuthentication" and have to set the name, loginpath or the timeout within sourcecode. In the past I was able to set timeout, etc... via web.config.

Is there any way to configure partially these things out of the box from a config-file? Or is this not supported anymore and I have to implement this configuration on my own? In the past this was a really comfortable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, Web.config file is used ONLY for IIS configuration, you cannot use it for application configuration, but there are new, better, more flexible configuration options that you can use.

There are multiple configuration sources that you can use, but in this example I'm using json. These examples are from working code in my [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth) project.

You can configure things in startup from configuration files.

First you add a config file in json format that maps to your class. You can see [my example class here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth/Models/SimpleAuthSettings.cs), and the json file it maps from [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth/blob/master/src/example.WebApp/simpleauthsettings.json)

```
builder.AddJsonFile("simpleauthsettings.json", optional: true);
```

Then, in the ConfigureServices method you configure your class to be wired up from the config system as shown

```
services.Configure<SimpleAuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SimpleAuthSettings"));
```

Then you add an IOptions accessor of your class to the method signature of the Configure method in the Startup.cs
The Dependency Injection will inject it into that method for you so you can use it there to configure things. Specifically I'm setting the cookie authentication scheme and name from my settings object.

The noteworthy part is that you can add whatever you want to the Configure method signature, and as long as it is something that has been registered in the ConfigureServices method, the DI will be able to inject it for you.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        // this file is the custom configuration file to hydrate my settings from
        builder.AddJsonFile("simpleauthsettings.json", optional: true);
        ....
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.Configure<SimpleAuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SimpleAuthSettings"));
        ....

    }

    // note that the DI can inject whatever you need into this method signature
    // I added IOptions<SimpleAuthSettings> authSettingsAccessor to the method signature
    // you can add anything you want as long as you register it in ConfigureServices
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IOptions<SimpleAuthSettings> authSettingsAccessor  
        )
    {
        ...
        // Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline
        SimpleAuthSettings authSettings = authSettingsAccessor.Value;

        var ApplicationCookie = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = authSettings.AuthenticationScheme,
            CookieName = authSettings.AuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index"),
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                //OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
            }
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(ApplicationCookie);

        // authentication MUST be added before MVC
        app.UseMvc();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but that means that I have to create configuration-structures on my own ? (what has been provided in the past out-of-the-box)

Comment: Yes that is the new world of dependency injection, there is no more static configuration, my advice is embrace it.

Comment: the thing to understand is that in order to make ASP.NET Core cross platform, they had to decouple it from IIS. and dependency injection really is a better way to configure things, once you get used to it you will grow to love it. so you can either stick with the comforts of the old platform and its familiar ways or jump in and get familiar and comfortable with the new platform, to use the new ASP.NET Core you are going to have to let go of many old ideas and embrace new ones

Comment: Sounds nice. I just want to be sure that I don't overlook something ... therefore I ask so intensely ;)